# ElementNotInteractable Exception in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I've been working on `Selenium` for quite some time and I've been getting error when I run the program in `Chrome` `v87.0.4280.88`. The version of the `Chrome Webdriver` I'm using is the same as `Chrome` Browser.

**TestNG_Demo**

```
@Test
    public void googleSearch() {

    //Go to google.com
    driver.get("https://google.com");

    //Enter text in search textbox
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Automation Step by Step");

    //click on search button
    //driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnK']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

}
```

**Error StackTrace**

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'EZL-OA-JACQUELI', ip: '192.168.43.77', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.88, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c..., userDataDir: C:\Users\lukegoh\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50405}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 1e96d9d5fffdd9fd39cdd647ab20081f

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
    at test.TestNG_Demo.googleSearch(TestNG_Demo.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

I have tried using `x-path` for Google Search Button and still give me error. May I know how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after your enter something in the google search text, it's make appear suggestion, this is make your button target `By.name("btnK")` covered.

Simple solution you can call `.submit()` after call send `.sendKeys("")`:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Automation Step by Step");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).submit();
```

**Image before - after text input**

[image: Before - After]

Answer (score 1):

The locator you have used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='btnK']"))
```

doesn't identifies the <kbd>Google Search</kbd> uniquely and your program is trying to interact with the wrong element.

[image: GoogleSearchButton]

Hence you see the error.

As an alternative you can use the following following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Automation Step by Step");
element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```